# No Such Table: 'Auth User' Error with Django Sign Up Form

Tags: python, django

Trying to register a user on my site, and getting this error when submitting.

`OperationalError: no such table: auth_user`

i've run makemigrations and migrate as suggested in other posts but it hasn't helped.

if i go to the accounts/sign_up page (which calls the sign_in view), enter the username and password, i get the aforementioned error.

Note that in my settings file, i am also bypassing auth_user model like so:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"`

this is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: auth_user) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\crstu\Desktop\JSPROJ\dealmazing\accounts\views.py" in sign_up
  46.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  161.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  153.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  364.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  402.             self.validate_unique()

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in validate_unique
  411.             self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in validate_unique
  930.         errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _perform_unique_checks
  1025.             if qs.exists():

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in exists
  651.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in has_results
  501.         return compiler.has_results()

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in has_results
  819.         return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py" in execute
  159.         return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py" in _record
  101.             return method(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\crstu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /accounts/sign_up/
Exception Value: no such table: auth_user
```

here is models.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin
)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import os
import datetime


def avatar_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('avatars', 'user_{0}', '{1}').format(
        instance.user.id, filename)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        if not username:
            username = email.split('@')[0]

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            username,
            password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_long_name(self):
        return "@{} ({})".format(self.username, self.email)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default='')
    avatar = models.ImageField('Avatar picture',
                               upload_to=avatar_upload_path,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def get_avatar_url(self):
        if self.avatar:
            return '/media/{}'.format(self.avatar)
        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?s=128&d=identicon'.format(
            '94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad'
        )


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

and forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django.core import validators

from . import models


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'avatar',
        ]


class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    verify_email = forms.EmailField(label = "Please verify email address")

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'verify_email',
            'avatar',
        ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = cleaned_data['email']
        verify = cleaned_data['verify_email']
        if email != verify:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "You need to enter same email in both fields."
            )
```

and views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from . import models
from . import forms

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields

def sign_in(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.user_cache is not None:
                user = form.user_cache
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(
                        reverse('home')
                    )
                else:
                    messages.error(
                        request,
                        "That user account has been disabled."
                    )
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request,
                    "Username or password is incorrect."
                )
    return render(request, 'accounts/sign_in.html', {'form': form})


def sign_up(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1']
            )
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(
                request,
                "You're now a user! You've been signed in, too."
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))  # TODO: go to profile
    return render(request, 'accounts/sign_up.html', {'form': form})


def sign_out(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "You've been signed out. Come back soon!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))


@login_required
def view_profile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofile
    return render(request, 'accounts/user_profile.html', {'profile':profile})

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.EditProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/profile')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = forms.EditProfileForm(instance=user.userprofile)
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)

@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request,form.user)
            return redirect('/accounts/profile')

    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', args)

@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
        return self.image.url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass the `UserCreationForm` to use your custom use model.

Adjusting the example in the docs, you would do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from accounts.models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields
```

Then use `CustomUserCreationForm` in your `sign_up` view.

See the docs on [custom users and the built in auth forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) for more info.

Comment: thanks --i updated my views file (also code above) and i now get `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: oh ...wait, ...d'oh just realized this needs to go in forms file...sorry about that, i'm sure i can get this working now. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in That case no import is needed I suppose, Remove below statment in files

```
models.py
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

forms.py
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: thanks--i just tried that and still getting the same error

Comment: Actually, I don't think the OP is using that `User` model at all, so I would remove those imports to avoid confusion.